# Unable to connect to data source because of SQLException

Tags: jboss, atg

In `ATG 10.2` facing some problem while running Motorprise application on JBOSS and using MySQLServer.

```
Unable to connect to data source because of SQLException: Could not enlist in transaction on entering meta-aware object!;
CONTAINER:atg.repository.RepositoryException; SOURCE:org.jboss.util.NestedSQLException:     Could not enlist in transaction on entering meta-aware object!; - nested throwable: (javax.transaction.SystemException: java.lang.Throwable: Unabled to enlist resource, see the previous warnings. tx=TransactionImple < ac, BasicAction: a618a4b:d503:525e
689c:1db status: ActionStatus.ABORT_ONLY >); - nested throwable: (org.jboss.resource.JBossResourceException: Could not enlist in transaction on entering meta-aware object!; - nested throwable: (javax.transaction.SystemException: java.lang.Throwable: Unabled to enlist resource, see the previous warnings. tx=TransactionImple < ac, BasicActi
on: a618a4b:d503:525e689c:1db status: ActionStatus.ABORT_ONLY >))
    at atg.adapter.gsa.GSAItemDescriptor.executeQuery(GSAItemDescriptor.java:8347)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JBoss by default assumes XA drivers and does not support calling multiple non-XA resources within the same transaction. To enable multiple non-XA resources in JBoss, add the property **com.arjuna.ats.jta.allowMultipleLastResources** to the `jbossjta-properties.xml` file, under the `<property depends="arjuna" name="jta">` tag:

```
<property depends="arjuna" name="jta">
  <property name="com.arjuna.ats.jta.allowMultipleLastResources" value="true"/>
```

You may still see warnings in your log file, but ATG applications will run correctly. To suppress these warnings, add the following to your jboss-log4j.xml file:

```
<category name="com.arjuna.atg.jta.logging">
  <priority value="ERROR"/>
</category>
```

This was the case in [ATG 9.3](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23095_01/Platform.93/ATGInstallGuide/html/s0202startingthesolidsqldatabase01.html) and I assume still holds true. Another quick reference to the cause is [here](http://blogs.adobe.com/livecycle/2011/06/javax-ejb-transactionrolledbacklocalexception-could-not-enlist-in-transaction-on-entering-meta-aware-object-error-seen-in-jboss-server-log.html)

Comment: Thank you.I tried with setting property in jboss file.but i am getting the same error.I am not sure why same thing is working properly in weblogic.

Answer (score 0):

Me to face the same problem. Resolved it by modifing my server\ATGPublishing\conf\jbossts-properties.xml file.

```
<properties depends="arjuna" name="jta">
<!--  SNIPPED FOR BREVITY -->
<property name="com.arjuna.ats.jta.allowMultipleLastResources" value="true" />
</properties>
```

Courtesy: http://branchbird.com/blog/the-atg-endeca-integration-part-2-loading-your-mdex/

Comment: Not sure how this answer adds more than the accepted answer above it.

Comment: If nothing else, it uses the file name `jbossts-properties.xml` which works for jboss 5.1.2 whereas `jbossjta-properties.xml` does not exist there.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was ejb transaction from ejb transaction, but they were leading by ejb container.
I can't change allowMultipleLastResources, therefore
I've tuned second ejb transaction by me directly.
And it solved the problem.

So second ejb in ejb-jar.xml
set Bean.